# Counting the number of objects in a DbSet via MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, opa

I have a `files` DbSet containing about 10k files.

Is there any way to retrieve the count of `files` with the help of the mongodb high-level API ?

Actually I'm doing a

`Iter.count(DbSet.iterator(/user))`

But it takes about 4 or 5 seconds to get the count.....

Any way to retrieve this count from MongoDB directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again Marcin, it worked with the low-level API !

Here's an example using the OCAML syntax:

I want to count all objects in the collection `files` (in database `files`) that have the `owner_id` field set to `96171629325147`.

```
my_db = MongoConnection.openfatal("default");

c = MongoCommands.count(my_db, "files", "files", some(Bson.opa2doc({owner_id=96171629325147})));

match c with
| {success=value} -> Resource.raw_text("DONE MO'FO ! Found {value} elements")
| {failure=e} -> Resource.raw_text("IT FAILED !!! WHY ??? {MongoCommon.string_of_failure(e)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid `count` is not implemented in high-level DB API :( But you can use low-level `MongoCommands.count`.

Comment: Indeed. Source code for the `count` function is on [github](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/master/lib/stdlib/apis/mongo/commands.opa#L369).

Comment: Could you provide an example of the MongoCommands.group for a simple "group by" like statement ?